# How $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $[a, b]$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

Let $(f_n)$ be defined and continuous on an interval $[a, b]$, and differentiable on $(a, b)$.

Let $c \in [a, b]$. Assume that $(f_n(c))$ converges and that $(f'_n)$ converges uniformly on $(a, b)$.

How to prove that then $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $[a, b]$.

I know that since for every $c \in [a,b]$, there exist an interval around $c$ in which $f_n$ converges uniformly, meaning for all $\epsilon >0$ there exist an $N>0$ such that $n>N$ implies $|f_n(c)-f(c)|<\epsilon$.

I know that $c$ is arbitray any where in $[a,b]$, but I don't know how to argue that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ formally.

Comment: Um.... Maybe you can use the fundamental theorem of calculus (an overkill I guess) : for any $n$ and $x\in [a, b]$, write $f_n(x) = f_n(c) + \int_c^x f'_n(s) ds$, then $f_n(x) - f_m(x) = f_n(c) - f_m(c) + \int_c^x (f'_n(s) - f'_m(s)) ds$

Comment: how to argue that $f_n$ converges uniformly on [a,b] formally. ?

Comment: Do you understand my hint above?

Comment: No I am not getting it, How it shows that $f_n$ converges ?

Comment: In my hint, can you show that the right hand side of the equation converges to $0$ as $m, n$ are large?

Comment: @John why is $f_n'$ Riemann integrable?

Comment: @zhw: You are right, they might not be so my idea is not working in general.

Comment: @John It's a nice simple proof in the case where the $f_n$ are $C^1,$ however, and this is the case you often see in applications.

Answer (score 2):

It's enough to show $f_n$ is uniformly Cauchy. Write

$$(1)\,\,\,\,f_n(x) - f_m(x) =  (f_n -  f_m)(x) -( f_n  - f_m)(c)+(f_n(c) - f_m(c)).$$

Use the MVT to see (1) equals

$$(f_n-f_m)'(d_x)(x-c) + (f_n(c) - f_m(c))
= (f_n'(d_x)-f_m'(d_x))(x-c) + (f_n(c) - f_m(c)).$$

Slap absolute values on to see this, in absolute value, is less than or equal to

$$(2)\,\,\,\,\sup_{[a,b]}|f_n'-f_m'|\cdot(b-a) + |f_n(c) - f_m(c)|.$$

Because $f_n'$ converges uniformly, it is uniformly Cauchy. The fact that $f_n(c)$ converges implies it is Cauchy. Thus (2) is small if $m,n$ are large enough, and this does it.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that, with the mean value theorem on $f_m(x)-f_n(x)$, we have:
$$|f_m(x) - f_n (x)| = |f_m(x) - f_m(c) + f_m(c) - f_n(x) +f_n(c) - f_n(c)| \\ \le |[f_m(x)-f_m(c)] - [f_n(x)-f_n(c)]|+|f_m(c)-f_n(c)| = |f_m'(t)-f_n'(t)||x-c| + |f_m(c)-f_n(c)|\\\le|f_m'(t)-f_n'(t)|(b-a) + |f_m(c)-f_n(c)|$$
Let $\epsilon>0$. We can pick $N \in \mathbf{N}$ such that for all $n>N$,

1) $|f_m'(t)-f_n'(t)|<\epsilon/[2(b-a)]$, by uniform continuity of derivatives

2) $|f_m(c)-f_n(c)|<\epsilon/2$ by the convergence at $x=c$.

Hence, $|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon.$ $f_n$ converges uniformly by Cauchy criterion.

Comment: How from 1 and 2 we can say , $|f(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon.$  ?

Comment: Plug the estimates in to our inequality

Comment: What is $f(x)$ and why do you think it's differentiable?

Comment: @zhw. Oops. You're right. Then we just use Cauchy